# ML Kit Vision API text recognition - How to check thin model has been downloaded

Tags: android, google-mlkit

I had an old device with Google play services not up-to-date and the phone wasn't able to download the Thin model for text recognition required by ML Kit. I was able to fix this issue by manually update google play services with the play store.

I would like to invite the user to update Google play services once the phone is not able to download the model.

Is there a way with new ML kit API for text recognition to check if the thin model has been downloaded?

> com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-text-recognition

Comment: Hi, if the model is not downloaded yet when processing an InputImage, an MlKitException.UNAVAILABLE will be thrown. However, this doesn't mean that the Google play service version is too old. Module download may take some time.

Comment: @ChenxiSong ok, so the only way is to catch this exception and show a dilog to inform the user.
As I said earlier in my case, this issue has been solved by updating google play services. In other words I could show a dialog to inform the user and suggest to update google play services

Comment: Yeah, this is the best effort for now.